# How can I listen for an alert popup and then automatically click ok when it pops up in javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup, alert

I would like to write a quick script that listens out for any alert popup, and then selects the 'OK' option once the alert pops up. However, I can't find any tutorials or documentation on listening for alerts. Is it possible to do this in Javascript?

Comment: You can't. Alerts cause all processing to freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't close three of javascript popups: alert(), prompt() and confirm() as they block JavaScript execution on page. Only user can close them or answer them.